# Is "petroblue" a color?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, word-request

I am wondering what would be an accurate word for the color of the prison uniform in the screenshot below, from a movie ([*Batman Begins*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins)).

The audio description of the color sounds to me like

> Bruce and his cellmate, in worn **petroblue uniforms**, step outside into a grey grim yard.

Is **petroblue** a word? Google doesn't bear it out. If I misheard it, what could the color be? The audio excerpt can be found [here](https://clyp.it/v5q2n5ic) (uploaded to Clyp, an easy audio sharing site).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounded like "petrol blue" taking into account the british accent, which I looked up and is actually a term used in GB
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/petrol_blue